# Using Printer Control Language (PCL) to Increase Left Margin

Tags: printing, printers, printer-control-language

We have a very old program that we print from where you are unable to change the left print margin in the program. I need to get it printing further from the left edge, ideally about 1 inch for binding. No issue with text going over the right edge as it doesn't get near that side of the page.

My idea was to use a custom separator page https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/131714 to issue a PCL command to increase the left margin.

We are using HP printers and I have tried using the standard windows example C:\Windows\System32\pcl.sep which works exactly as expected.

This is my attempt at a .sep file (am saving in the system32 folder)

```
\
\H1B\L%-12345X
\H1B\LE
\H1B\L&l4000U
\H1B\L&a+3000H
\
```

I've tried a couple of variations, but it does absolutely nothing, my document just prints like normal.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the application is explicitly setting the margins,
thus undoing anything you are trying in the .sep file. I am not familiar with the .sep file at all.

In the PCL context, if you are printing in duplex you want the extra binding on the left for the front side and on the right for the backside. The PCL command to end up with a 1 inch binding margin would be something like &l540U The 540U shifts the image 3/4 inch which when added to the existing minimum 1/4 inch margin gives you a 1 inch total.

Can you direct your output to a file to see what is actually being sent to the printer?